# How many meanings does the term "Brand new" have?

Tags: meaning, phrases, adjectives

Brand new, at least in my eyes, has two different possible meanings.

The phrase "Brand new" can be defined either as a product of a new brand, or a new product of an already existing brand. Both meanings could be used simultaneously when referring to a product of a new brand, since that product would also technically be a new product, unless of course the product the new brand creates was already a product a different brand already created.

Are both meanings correct? Can both be used interchangeably to describe any new product? Are there more meanings to the phrase "brand new", and is there a possibility that only one of these two definitions of "brand new" is correct?

Comment: This: *""Brand new" can be defined either as a product of a new brand* doesn't seem right to me - can you expand on this?

Comment: I'd say that 'brand' just means that it's come from a manufacturer, as opposed to handmade. If I make myself a stool, even if it's from new wood, the stool isn't 'brand new'. It's just 'new'. If I buy one from IKEA, the 'brand' applies. I've never heard it carry any sense of a 'new brand'.

Comment: The idiom "brand new", as an adjective, simply means something which is (ostensibly) substantially different from previous items of the same class.  It is also an incredibly overused/abused term and nearly meaningless.  The term has nothing to do with "brand" as used to refer to a manufacturer's mark.

Answer (score 2):

​***[Brand new](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/brand-new)*** is  an idiomatic expression that means:

> - completely new, especially not yet used:
>
>   - *How can he afford to buy himself a brand new car?*
>   - *Her coat looked as if it was brand new.*

Cambridge Dictionary

The expression you are referring to according to your description is:

> *new product* and  *new brand product*